# JavaScript - case sensitivity issue within an object/property

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, case

I have an issue with JavaScript case sensitivity and I will need your valuable piece of advice here. I have the following object created:

```
var foo = function () {
  this.myColor1 = '#000000';
  this.MyColor2 = '#FF2000';
  this.MyCOLOR3 = '#FFFFFF'; 
}
```

as you can see, each property may come in any case form, lowercase, uppcase, mixed, etc. These values are coming from a database and I don't have control onto them.

I want to be able to call them ignoring the case sensitivity. For example, I would like to be able to call them like this:

```
console.log(foo.mycolor1);
// or
console.log(foo.myColor1);
```

I guess my only approach to achieve this, would be to convert everything in, let's say, lowercase when I define those, and then, when I call them back to convert my request into lowercase again.

A little piece of background here; my aim is to provide an SDK to a few developers that they will write their own code for a platform I am working on. These values will be saved by the developers themselves into a database. For some reason, all those values are stored in lowercase. So, I either have to tell them 'no matter how you set them, you should request everything in lowercase', or, ideally, I should find a way to convert everything before their request is post.

An idea would be to write a method, and tell them to make the request like this

```
foo('mycolor1');
```

foo, is going to be a function that would handle the case sensitivity easily. But, I would prefer to use the foo.mycolor1 notation, so ... your help is needed :)

FYI, jQuery is available!

Thank you,
Giorgoc

Comment: Um, Wouldn't it be wise to figure out why it is saved as lowercase?

Comment: I think you answered your own question here:  `"I guess my only approach to achieve this, would be to convert everything in, let's say, lowercase when I define those, and then, when I call them back to convert my request into lowercase again."`   :)

Comment: epascarello, I already did this and I have figured out that it's impossible to avoid this. The way it's been inserted is done by using query of queries of CFML which converts everything in uppercase, hence case-sensitivity is totally lost.

tamelyn, i agree. that's why I am seeking for a way to send my requests to lowercase no matter how the developers are going to type their property names.

Answer (score 0):

when you render the javascript from DB use toLower() to set the variables names... and then reference them in lower case...

Comment: yes, that's the approach I describe. that's why i asked, "how" to do this, without using a method, but by direct reference to my properties by ignoring the case sensitivity.

Comment: also, ideally i don't want to force my developers to write in lower-case. I want them to use whatever they want. but behind the scenes, i want to convert everything in lowercase. that's what i describe above.

Comment: for this razon you must render instead "this.myColor1 = '#000000';", "this.mycolor1 = '#000000';"